# learn training file new letters in windows (for c# app)

Tags: tesseract

I would like to learn my training file for tesseract new letters. I want use win 10 (*I won't use linux*) - for use tesseract Nuget-package in c#.net app.

[image] [image][image]

I tried jTessBoxEditor but it's not working (first time error in registry, than cannot found fonts, than problem with java, than text2image doesn't work properly...). Editor SunnyPage could not even load the image without fail.

1. which program use for separating letters and creating training file as windows user
2. should I use tesseract or other OCR engine? It looks like tesseract isn't windows-user friendly
3. please post example training file for this three images - if there is any need of preprocessing (scale etc.) it should be done programaticaly (c#.net)

Answer (score 0):

**Which program use for separating letters and creating a training file?**

Try this one: https://github.com/skotz/captcha-breaking-library

or:

**OpenCV**

OpenCV is a popular framework for computer vision and image processing. It is easy to use OpenCV to process the CAPTCHA images. It has a Python API so you can use it directly from Python.

**Keras**

Keras is a deep learning framework written in Python. It makes it easy to define, train and use deep neural networks with minimal coding.

**TensorFlow**

TensorFlow is Google’s library for machine learning. If you will be coding in Keras, but Keras doesn’t actually implement the neural network logic itself. Instead, it uses Google’s TensorFlow library behind the scenes to do the heavy lifting.

This involves either brute-forcing the captcha or running OCR algorithms on it to try and detect what is written in the captcha.
If you want to implement your own CAPTHA an algorithm please look into that abstract: http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~cernyad2/TextCaptchaPdf/DESIGNING%20CAPTCHA%20ALGORITHM%20SPLITTING%20AND%20ROTATING.pdf

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.800.3065&rep=rep1&type=pdf